# Non-trivial transform of XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to transform XML from one format to another format using XSLT but this is complex (for me at least) and I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to do the following logic:

(written in C#-like pseudocode)

1. Update the Top element for each Machine based on the contents of the fourth Axis element (if it exists) but only when the contents of the Type subelement has the value "Rotary". If this condition is met, then Top should be formatted like so:

   ```
   <Top>
       <Axis>xxx</Axis> 
       <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
       <IsManual>false</IsManual>
   </Top>
   ```

where xxx would be the value of the AxisID/Name element.

2. Replace the contents of  with the same condition as described in item 1 with the exception that the fifth Axis element would be examined (as opposed to the fourth which is examined in item 1).
3. Update the Mode element based on the content of the fourth and fifth Axis elements for each machine. If the Type element for both fourth and fifth axis have the value Rotary, then Mode has the value 256. If only one of them has the value rotary, then Mode has the value 128. If neither have the value Rotary, then the value of Mode element should be 0.
4. Remove the current Ordering, IsIndexed, and IsManual elements. This one is currently implemented but I wonder if this will need to change based on my new requirements listed above in 1-3

XSLT: (what I currently have)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:cd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <!-- Copy everything not subject to the exceptions below -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Ignore the ordering IsIndexed, IsManual elements -->
  <xsl:template match="cd:Ordering|cd:IsIndexed|cd:IsManual" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Machine>
    <Price>120000</Price>
    <Properties>
      <Axes>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>X</Name>
            <Type>X</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>Y</Name>
            <Type>Y</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>Z</Name>
            <Type>Z</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>R1</Name>
            <Type>B</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Rotary</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>R2</Name>
            <Type>C</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
      </Axes>
      <Ordering>XR1YR2Z</Ordering>
      <Rotaries>
        <Top i:nil="true" />
        <Bottom i:nil="true"/>
        <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
        <IsManual>false</IsManual>
        <Mode>222</Mode>
      </Rotaries>
    </Properties>
  </Machine>
</ArrayOfMachine>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Machine>
    <Price>120000</Price>
    <Properties>
      <Axes>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>X</Name>
        <Type>X</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>Y</Name>
            <Type>Y</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>Z</Name>
            <Type>Z</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>R1</Name>
            <Type>B</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Rotary</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>R2</Name>
            <Type>C</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
      </Axes>
      <Ordering>XR1YR2Z</Ordering>
      <Rotaries>
        <Top>
             <Axis>R1</Axis> 
                     <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
                     <IsManual>false</IsManual>
        </Top>
        <Bottom i:nil="true" /> 
        <Mode>128</Mode> 
      </Rotaries>
    </Properties>
  </Machine>
</ArrayOfMachine>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your pseudocode - please explain the required logic in plain English.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've made an attempt to be more clear. Let me know if there are still ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that modifies the `Top` element of a `Machine` whose 4th `Axis` has a `Type` value of `"Rotary"`. The value of the new `Axis` element is taken from `AxisID/Name` element of the said `Axis`.

I believe you should be able to expand this to the other two tasks.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine"
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine"
exclude-result-prefixes="cd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis[4]/cd:Type='Rotary']/cd:Rotaries/cd:Top">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Axis>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::cd:Properties/cd:Axes/cd:Axis[4]/cd:AxisID/cd:Name"/>
        </Axis> 
        <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
        <IsManual>false</IsManual>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This answer seems to resolve all but item 3. Not sure how to handle the counting of the number of axes that are of type Rotary and then setting the element's value based on that count.

Comment: Is it sufficient to count any and all axes that are of type Rotary? Or is it necessary to limit the count to only axes #4 and #5 of this type?

Comment: Total count. Also, if I wanted to modify the top element to represent the first axis that meets this condition would it be cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type='Rotary'][1]/cd:Rotaries/cd:Top? And, if so, what would the value of statement be? I can pose this as a separate question if that is more appropriate.

Comment: From the context of `Mode`, you can use `count(ancestor::cd:Properties/cd:Axes/cd:Axis[cd:Type='Rotary'])`. I believe you want to multiply that by 128 to get the final value. -- Yes, I think it would be better to start a new question.

Comment: So <xsl:template match="cd:Machine/cd:Properties/cd:Rotaries/cd:Mode">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::cd:Properties/cd:Axes/cd:Axis[cd:Type='Rotar‌​y'])" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> ?If so,  I keep getting a value of 0.

Comment: I had a typo. Marking this as answered.